# Python Turtle array error

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm new in Python and I've tried to make "Man,Don't get angry." on Turtle but I have this error:
[This is the output from the console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsyX2.png)

And the code:
[The picture of the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ldxr0.png)

Thanks, if you help me. If you need more of the code I will show it.

Comment: Post all code and errors here directly as text.

Comment: Your array `p` starts with string objects that you are replacing with `Turtle`s.  The error says that you are trying to call the function `goto` on a string instead of on a `Turtle`, which would indicate that there is a mistake in your initialization code.

Answer (score 0):

The `p` variable starts out as a list of lists of strings.  The strings get replaced with turtles:

```
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        while h < 16:
            p[i][j]=turtle.Turtle()
            # ...
            h+=1
```

The logic for looping over `h` is incorrect, you effectively set `p[0][0]` to a turtle 16 times and leave the rest as strings.  Which fails later on when you try to use them as turtles.  Instead consider:

```
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        p[i][j]=turtle.Turtle()
        # ...
        h+=1
```

You don't need to explicitly test if `h` is 16 as it is being incremented 4 * 4 times.